# User.Identity.Name como parámetro "filtro" no funciona FormView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estoy tratando de usar la variable de sesión para que solamente me muestre el `FormView` los datos de ese usuario pero me está mostrando todos los datos de la  vista.

**formulario.aspx**:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="vw_ConsultaClientesPolizas" EmptyDataText="No se ha encontrado ningún registro" RenderOuterTable="False" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="UserId">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Nombre:
        <asp:Label ID="CLI_NOMBRELabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CLI_NOMBRE") %>' />

        Primer Apellido:
        <asp:Label ID="CLI_APELLIDO1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CLI_APELLIDO1") %>' />

        Segundo Apellido:
        <asp:Label ID="CLI_APELLIDO2Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CLI_APELLIDO2") %>' />
        <br />
        Fecha de Nacimiento:
        <asp:Label ID="CLI_NACIMIENTOLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CLI_NACIMIENTO") %>' />
        <br />
        Genero:
        <asp:Label ID="CLI_SEXOLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CLI_SEXO") %>' />
        <br />
        Numero de póliza:
        <asp:Label ID="POL_NumPolizaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POL_NumPoliza") %>' />
        <br />
        Estado de póliza:
        <asp:Label ID="POL_EstadoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POL_Estado") %>' />
        <br />
        Vigencia desde:
        <asp:Label ID="POL_EfectoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POL_Efecto") %>' />

        Vigencia hasta:
        <asp:Label ID="POL_FechaVencimientoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POL_FechaVencimiento") %>' />
        <br />
        Placa:
        <asp:Label ID="POL_AliasRiesgoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POL_AliasRiesgo") %>' />
        <br />
        Total recibo anual: $
        <asp:Label ID="POL_TotalReciboAnualLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POL_TotalReciboAnual") %>' />
        <br />
        Póliza Colectiva:
        <asp:Label ID="POL_EsColectivoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POL_EsColectivo") %>' />
        <br />
        Descripción:
        <asp:Label ID="POL_DescRiesgoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POL_DescRiesgo") %>' />
        <br />
        Aseguradora:
        <asp:Label ID="CIA_ImagenLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CIA_Imagen") %>' />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="vw_ConsultaClientesPolizas" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Promotec_Web2017_CS %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [CLI_NOMBRE], [CLI_APELLIDO1], [CLI_APELLIDO2], [CLI_NACIMIENTO], [CLI_SEXO], [POL_NumPoliza], [POL_Estado], [POL_Efecto], [POL_FechaVencimiento], [POL_AliasRiesgo], [POL_TotalReciboAnual], [POL_EsColectivo], [POL_DescRiesgo], [CIA_Imagen] FROM [vw_ConsultaClientesPolizas] WHERE ([Username] = @Username AND [POL_NumPoliza] LIKE '%' + @POL_NumPoliza + '%' OR [POL_AliasRiesgo] LIKE '%' + @POL_AliasRiesgo + '%') ORDER BY [POL_FechaVencimiento], [CLI_ESTADO]">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FormView2" Name="Username" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" DefaultValue="<% User.Identity.Name %>" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtPolizas" Name="POL_NumPoliza" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="%" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtPlaca" Name="POL_AliasRiesgo" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="%" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Buscar" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-danger" />
```

**formulario.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
    else
    {
        vw_ConsultaClientesPolizas.SelectParameters["Username"].DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name;
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["Username"].DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    vw_ConsultaClientesPolizas.SelectParameters["Username"].DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto:
Fue necesario poner un Textbox con el código para que funcionara.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsuario" runat="server" Text='<%# User.Identity.Name %>' Visible="False" />
```

Luego tomar el filtro desde ese textbox, ninguna idea de porque pero así funcionó.

Comment: Podrías usar un HiddenField, en lugar del TextBox oculto.

Comment: Por algún extraño motivo no funciona :s